# Support in Select and Update in the same table creating a ranking by date

Tags: mysql, nested

[image: Columns of the DB in the image]

Respected all,
I will appreciate your help with the following query:
Objective: To create a ranking indicating by day, which is the best selling store, ie the one that sells the most, will be the number 1, and so on.
The fields in the table are:
Date, Store, Sales, Rank_Sales_By_Date,
I would like to know if it is possible with a single query, or with which method, I can update the column Rank_Sales_By_Date, with this information, at the moment I have a partial query, filtered with a date ('2017-02-19'), but the object Is that it does, ranked by date, for all dates, I am not an expert, therefore I will appreciate your invaluable help with this. Thank you. Then the query I have, I need to do the tour by date and the update in the column rank_sales:

The update is in the same table, but I have not detected the appropriate method.

Thank you very much in advance,

Columns,

```
Date, Store, Sales, Rank_Sales_By_Date
----  -----  -----  ------------------
```

Comment: I tried the first query, but I do not know how to update it ..:                             SELECT
  store, date, Sales AS Sales_var,
(
  SELECT COUNT(Sales) + 1
  FROM store
  WHERE (Sales > Sales_var) AND date = '2017-02-19'
  ) AS rank
 FROM store
WHERE date = '2017-02-19'
GROUP BY store, date
ORDER BY Sales_var DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume you have a uniqe key (date, store).

i will suggest to solve your question with the follow query (**using User-Defined Variables**):

```
set @LastDate= Null, @LastSales= NULL, @CurRange=NULL;
update Sale_Table
set Rank_Sales_By_Date= if(@LastDate<=>Date, 
                               if(Sales<=>@LastSales, 
                                     @CurRange, 
                                     @CurRange:=@CurRange+1),
                               @CurRange:=1 + cast((@LastDate:=`Date`) as DATE) - `date` + (@LastSales:=Sales) - Sales)
order by Date, Sales desc, Store;
```

I think it is not clear for you the last part `(cast((@LastDate:=`Date`) as DATE) -`date`+ (@LastSales:=Sales) - Sales)`. the value of it is always 0, but i use it  to assign the Value of field Date to variable @LastDate and the value of sales to variable @LastSales.

With this query two Stores that have the same sales in the same day will have the same range.

Comment: That works Perfect, Thank you so, very much for your help!
Problem Solved !!!!! :)

Comment: Hi H.K.  thanks and I hope that you still find yourself on the radar, your help was fantastic but after I checked it, I realized that the order was given consecutively and I was not doing it in the field in a descending way .. how could you Help please? regards

Comment: Hi dear leocp    you can use: set @LastDate= Null, @LastSales= NULL, @CurRange=NULL;
select *,  if(@LastDate<=>Date, 
                               if(Sales<=>@LastSales, 
                                     @CurRange, 
                                     @CurRange:=@CurRange+1),
                               @CurRange:=1 + cast((@LastDate:=`Date`) as DATE) - `date` + (@LastSales:=Sales) - Sales) 
           As Rank_Sales_By_Date
from Sale_Table
order by Date, Sales desc, Store;    With this select statement you can do what y want. If you wish a help y can send me a mail.

Comment: Hi H.K.
Excellent, I run the query and in effect, it shows the expected result, but how much I regret to tell you, I could not be able to construct the statement for the UPDATE, I really try!, would you don't mind, tell me please, what's the correct syntax would be for the UPDATE ? (Destination field = sales.rank_sales_by_date)
Again, a million thanks!